# Is there a Non-blocking NIO version of Socket Appender for Log4j?

Tags: sockets, log4j, nio

I am implementing a logging system for scattered web load testing application.

It requires remote agents to send log events to controller frequently (5-10 events per second) with large log messages (100K-500K per log event).

I want to know is there a non-blocking NIO implementation for Socket Appender for Log4j ? If yes, will it be able to fullfil the requirements?

Thanks,
Ellick

Answer (score 1):

Check [AsyncAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) out.

Here's a blog entry with a usage example and a few tips:
http://www.spartanjava.com/2009/asynchronous-logging-with-log4j/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

That's up to 5MB per second. Using or not using NIO won't make much difference. I would be more concerned about whether the network can handle that, from multiple sources.